Adding whitespace exclusion to the regular expression in Javascript
I have difficulty with regular expression.
Regular expression requirements: from 3 to 20 characters, Latin, may contain numbers, but not consist of them, without spaces, without special characters (hyphens and underscores are allowed).
At the moment, my expression looks like this:
const regexp = /^(?=.*[A-Za-z]{1,}[0-9]{0,}).{3,20}$/;

I will be grateful for any help
UPDATE
"May contain numbers, but not consist of them" means at least one letter.

may contain numbers, but not consist of them sounds confusing ... can you add to the question examples of what should match and what should not

you can use a negative lookahead for excluding strings with spaces
(?!.*\s)

/^(?=.*[A-Za-z]{1,}[0-9]{0,})(?!.*\s).{3,20}$/


What is wrong with the regular expression? I expect someone will just write an answer for you, but you should post a list of strings that are accepted and should be, that are accepted and should not be, are not accepted and should be, and that are not accepted and shouldn't be. /^[\w-]{3,20}$/m should catch all cases you described except "not-numbers-only". If it cannot contain only numbers I would check that after the fact (two simple regexes may be faster than a complicated one). Can it start with a hyphen? Adding a list of acceptable and non-acceptable strings, and using https://regex101.com/ are your friend.
